# Import module installed in venv

Tags: python, package, python-venv

I am trying to call a custom module installed in my virtualenv. The module built by myself has the following structure:

```
test
├── README.md
├── setup.py
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── module_x
│       └── abc.py
└── tests
```

setup.py looks like following:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

with open('README.md', 'r') as f:
    long_description = f.read()

setup(
    name='test',
    version='0.1.0',
    author='me',
    description='description',
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    packages=find_packages('src'),
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    install_requires=[''],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'test=module_x.abc:main'
        ],
    }
)
```

Inside of the `abc.py`, I am using the following code:

```
class RandomClass:

    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg
        info()

    def info():
        print(self.msg)

def main(msg):
    RandomClass(msg)
```

**init**.py looks like

```
from .module_x.abc import main
```

The egg was installed using `pip install -e .`.

**UPDATED**

How can I call the module in a new Python script like `from test import main`? Currently it works just like `from test.src import main` and I don't want to know the whole structure of the package. In the future will exist also module_y, module_z etc. My assumption is that I would need to modify something in the setup.py.

Comment: Does `import test` not work?

Comment: @tripleee: Thanks for your reply. I've just updated the question, maybe will be more clear.